# Python 3.5 + PyQt5 приложение отрабатывает дважды

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.5, pycharm

**Задание:** в заданном русском тексте выбрать слова, которые без искажения могут быть написаны латинскими буквами, например: *СВЕТА РОЕТ РОВ, ВОВКА СЕЕТ ОВЁС*.

**Среда разработки:** PyCharm (Python 3.5 + PyQt5, Windows 10)

**Проблема:** программа по каким-то непонятным причинам работает дважды. Например, метод *"on_btn_solve_clicked"* отработал как надо, далее программа идёт в *"sys.exit(app.exec_())"* и потом обратно в метод *"on_btn_solve_clicked"*, из-за этого на экран нужная информация дублируется (см. рис.).

**PS:** определил это с помощью отладчика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так быть не должно, в правильном варианте должен быть ответ просто "*СВЕТА*"

**Программа состоит из двух файлов:** *Main.py* и *main.iu* (*main.ui* находится в папке uis, создавал файл в *Qt Designer*).

**Код из файла Main.py:**

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        loadUi('uis/main.ui', self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Работа со строками в Python')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/logo.png'))

        self.btn_solve.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_solve_clicked)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_btn_solve_clicked(self):
        my_letters = 'АВСТРХОНКМУЕ' # буквы, совпадающие с английскими

        text = self.textEdit_text.toPlainText() # получаем наш текст
        letters = list(text) # текст => список букв

    '''
    Полное или правильное слово - слово, в котором все буквы соответсвуют английском буквам.
    Неполное слово - солово, в котором есть буквы, не совпадающие с английскими буквами.
    '''

        sb = [] # контейнер для слов
        is_full_word = True

        i = 0
        while i < len(letters): # прогоняем каждую букву и даже пробелы
            if is_full_word is True: # слова МОЯ, ТВОЯ не пройдут, ибо это неполные слова

                if letters[i] in my_letters: # построение слова по буквам, если соответсвует требованиям
                    sb.append(letters[i])
                elif letters[i] == ' ': # любое слово оканчивается пробелом
                    self.textEdit_words.append(''.join(map(str, sb))) # добавляем готовое слово в textEdit
                    is_full_word = True
                    sb = [] # обнуляем контейнер, ибо слово уже добавлено в textEdit
                else: # если правильной буквы нет, значит слово будет не полным
                    is_full_word = False
                    sb = [] # обнуляем контейнер, ибо слово неполное, смысла его хранить нет

                i += 1
            else: # когда нет правильной буквы ищем пробел где заканчивается слово
                if letters[i] == ' ':
                    is_full_word = True # нашли пробел, значит следующая буква будет началом нового слова

                i += 1

        if is_full_word is True and len(sb) != 0: # если слово одно или не имеет после себя пробела
            self.textEdit_words.append(''.join(map(str, sb)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

То есть последовательность выполнения такая: *"on_btn_solve_clicked"* => *"sys.exit(app.exec_())"* => *"on_btn_solve_clicked"*

**Код из файла main.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>611</width>
    <height>365</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>420</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit_words">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>310</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>291</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit_text">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>291</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_1">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>130</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>41</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Текст</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>430</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>55</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Слова</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_solve">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>280</y>
     <width>151</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Выполнить</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_clear">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>190</x>
     <y>280</y>
     <width>151</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Очистить</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_task_1">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>320</y>
     <width>601</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>В заданном русском тексте выбрать слова, которые без искажения могут быть написаны</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_task_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>340</y>
     <width>521</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>латинскимии буквами, например: СВЕТА РОЕТ РОВ, ВОВКА СЕЕТ ОВЁС</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: `if is_full_word is True` прекрасно заменяется `if is_full_word` тоже самое касается и `len(sb) != 0` -> `sb`. Например, правильно: `if is_full_word and sb:`. `map(str, sb)` не нужно, т.к. у вас sb и так список строк

Comment: Спасибо за корректировку, я только-только начал изучать python. Вы знаете как решить мою проблему?

Comment: Пока не знаю -- делаю. Но уверен, проблема в алгоритме

Comment: Кст, вы молодец, что предоставили и код и ui -- очень удобно работать. Я бы добавил еще замечание -- у вас виджеты расположены на форме вручную, из-за этого при изменении размера формы они статичны. Помещайте виджеты на компоновщики (layout), например QVBoxLayout. QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout и т.п.

Comment: Я по отладчику смотрел, когда метод заканчивается, то перескакивает на sys.exit(app.exec_()), а потом обратно на тот же метод. Вроде бы алгоритм должен работать правильно.

Comment: Нашел решение, но немного костыльное. Сейчас напишу в ответе

Comment: Кст, хотите покажу как можно ваш алгоритм в пару строк уложить? :)

Comment: Давайте! Будет интересно!

Comment: Обновил ответ  ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение проблемы двойного вызова:

Заменить:

```
# ...
self.btn_solve.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_solve_clicked)

@pyqtSlot()
def on_btn_solve_clicked(self):
```

- Если оставить неявное соединение:

  ```
  # Эту строку удалить
  # self.btn_solve.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_solve_clicked)

  @pyqtSlot()
  def on_btn_solve_clicked(self):
  ```
- Если нужно явно соединять:

  ```
  self.btn_solve.clicked.connect(self.solve)

  def solve(self):
  ```

---

`Qt` может автоматически соединить слоты имеющие спец-имена, например: `on_btn_solve_clicked` обозначает: соедини меня с сигналом *clicked* у объекта *btn_solve*. А последующий `self.btn_solve.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_solve_clicked)` делает еще одно подключение к сигналу, что вызывает двойной вызов слота при одном сигнале

---

Алгоритм из вопроса можно упростить через регулярные выражения (нужно импортировать `import re`):

```
# ...    

@pyqtSlot()
def on_btn_solve_clicked(self):
    # Исходный текст
    text = self.textEdit_text.toPlainText()

    # Буквы, совпадающие с английскими
    for word in re.findall(r'\b[АВСТРХОНКМУЕ]+\b', text):
        self.textEdit_words.append(word)
```

Тогда, для строки `СВЕТА РОЕТ РОВ, ВОВКА СЕЕТ ОВЁС` получится список: `['СВЕТА', 'РОЕТ', 'РОВ', 'ВОВКА', 'СЕЕТ']`

- `\b` – ищет границы слов
- `[АВСТРХОНКМУЕ]` – описывает что ищем
- `+` – говорит, что искать нужно минимум от 1 символа

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта! Спасибо, что не прошли мимо и помогли мне!

Comment: Если ответ понравился, поставьте плюс :)

Comment: У меня дублируется нажатие для следующего кода: self.III.clicked.connect(lambda: print("wtf")) III - это название кнопки. Где тут спец-имена ? Почему это происходит?

Comment: У вас где-то дублируется `self.III.clicked.connect` либо клик происходит два раза. Спец-имена? А у вас нет метода `on_III_clicked`?